# Re-synching Mercurial repositories after a machine re-installtion

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I just had to re-install the system drive on my PC.
As a result I've a load of Mercurial repositories on another drive that have lost their association with the repository server.
All the local repositories are up to date as I'm the only one working on them and everything was synched before the PC's re-installation.

I'm using Tortoise hg and BitBucket.

I don't want to have to delete the repositories and re-clone them to get it all working again as this strikes me as a long way round an needless use of bandwith.

Is there a simple way to tell a local repository to re-connect to the repo on the server?

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you just edit the `default` entry in the `[paths]` section of the repos `.hg/hgrc` file.  You can see what it's currently set to with the `hg paths` command.  Correct it and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I just needed to let the PC restart and catch up.
Eventually the overlay icons appeared and everything seems fine.